# Tooltips in NSTextView/NSTextfields

Tags: cocoa, uikit, foundation, xcode9.2

I want to display tooltips over parts of an attributed string, and thought that using an NSToolTipAttributeName attribute on the required ranges would do the trick but I can't get it to work. 
I am trying in MACOS, Xcode (9.2)

```
NSString *fullString = @"Create a new tooltip";

NSString *compareString =@"tooltip";

NSRange tooltipRange = [fullString rangeOfString: compareString]; 

[senderTextView.textStorage addAttribute:NSToolTipAttributeName
                        value:@"Custom tooltip"
                        range:tooltipRange];

[senderTextView.textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
     value:[NSColor redColor] range:tooltipRange];
```

The word "tooltip" is shown in red as expected, but no tooltip appears when I hover over it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do this, using the `NSToolTipAttributeName` in combination with `NSLinkAttributeName`, e.g.:

```
NSMutableDictionary* labelAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
labelAttributes[NSToolTipAttributeName] = @"Tooltip";
labelAttributes[NSLinkAttributeName] = @"Link";
NSAttributedString* labelString = [NSAttributedString
    attributedString:@"Display"]
    withAttributes:labelAttributes];
```

Being careful not to forget `displaysLinkToolTips = YES` on the `NSTextView`.

Alternately, you can use the `NSView` [Tooltips API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483541-tooltip?language=objc), which provides:

```
- (NSToolTipTag)addToolTipRect:(NSRect)rect owner:(id)owner userData:(void *)data;
```

Comment: This is wrong, there's no need for a link attribute (and no need for `displaysLinkToolTips`). Tooltips can be presented on their own.